# Is there a way to avoid repeating types for destructing arguments in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

E.g. I have functions like this a lot:

```
function fn({
  required,
  optional = 0,
}: {
  required: number,
  optional: number,
}) {}
```

The `optional: number` is repeated/unnecessary because TS can already infer it from `optional = 0`. Is it possible to avoid repeating this type?

Comment: To be clear you're talking about omitting one line right? I can't see why you need this.

Comment: I like optimization and this is clearly suboptimal at the moment, it's more about clean code than saving keystrokes

Comment: I don't think leaving it off is any cleaner. You're just being explicit about what the type signature is, rather than leaving it to inference. But you're already being explicit about one part of the request object, so why not.

Answer (score 0):

since you are referring to a type, you can declare the type as a `interface`

```
interface IParam {
  required: number,
  optional?: number,
}

function fn( { required, optional = 0, } : IParam) {

}
```

Comment: But that's just what he is doing now.

Comment: @dwjohnston when he feels "The `optional: number` is repeated/unnecessary " in the code,

Comment: Right, but you have declared that optional type, in your `IParam` interface. He's asking if you can do it _without_  declaring it.

Comment: the `optional` type has to be declared in the `IParam` type, otherwise object destructuring assignment will fails. by declaring a common type as `interface` hs/she can avoid writing the same object type repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do it with destructuring and a type definition since typescript will complain about extra properties on the type/interface. If you really want to avoid defining the type of optional and have it inferred from the default argument you can take it out of IParam and pass it as a separate argument to fn.

```
function fn( {required}:{required: number}, optional=0) {
}
```

or you can avoid a type definition altogether by providing defaults to all values.

```
function fn( { required = 0, optional = 0 }) {
}
```

Personally I would still use your original approach in the question where optional is part of the explicitly defined interface.